# Tint2 "invisible" with second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, tint2

This worked yesterday not sure what changed. Other than my battery running dry, also I'm running 13.04.

Started up app tint2. Laptop booted plugged into second monitor via vga.

tint2 was functioning it was just not visible, aka. a window full screen still left space for the taskbar, and can select apps from the "invisible" bar.

Logged out and back in, same thing. Tried uninstalling and then reinstalling, same result. Then took it off start up apps and tried without the second monitor, ah ha that worked. After plugging in the other monitor I got this

> (process:11352): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_foreach: assertion
>   `version == hash_table->version' failed 
>   real transparency on... depth:
>   32 xRandr: Found crtc's: 3 xRandr: Linking output LVDS1 with crtc 0
>   tint2 : another systray is running pid=10710 tint2 : nb monitor 1, nb
>   monitor used 1, nb desktop 1
>
> (process:11352): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_foreach: assertion
>   `version == hash_table->version' failed real transparency on... depth:
>   32 xRandr: Found crtc's: 3 xRandr: Linking output LVDS1 with crtc 0
>   xRandr: Linking output VGA1 with crtc 1 tint2 : another systray is
>   running pid=10710 tint2 : nb monitor 3, nb monitor used 3, nb desktop
>   1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have a configuration similar to:

[image]

If yes, according to [this thread](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=30999) that is what confuses tint2. So the idea is the have the first dipsplay positioned in the topleft corner and everything should be fine. Like:

[image]

Note: The application in the screenshots is called [arandr](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/arandr/) and it is responsible for writing xrandr configuration files.

Comment: Oh God! Just wasted 45 minutes installing and reinstalling tint2. Thanksa lot @Matyas! I still don have a solution, but at least now I know the cause.

Comment: ty @matyas, u saved me a lot of headache. did you found any fix for this? i would like to position my first screen lower :/

Comment: Sorry, there is no solution to it yet. So you cannot position a panel (tint2 or xfce4-panel) across 2 unaligned screens. Which kind of makes sense, because just imagine you wish to place a bar that spans both displays. If you'd put it At the top of the lower one, the bar would stretch across the middle of the display that is higher...

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks. Tested like 30 minutes different configs. None helped. But changing place of second screen worked perfectly. Many thanks. Should be added on tint2 docs.